# How can I simulate a loss of session state

Tags: asp.net, iis

Is there anyway I can simulate the loss of the InProc session state? I am trying to see how my app handles if such a thing happens. Can this be done from IIS Manager?

Thanks,

AJ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Restart the application pool.

Answer (score 2):

Even more easily just modify your applications web.config, open it in Notepad and add a whitespace at the end. Click-Save and your AppDomain will recycle (Not your Application Pool), this is more lightweight/quick way of having the same behavior.

Comment: You can touch the dll of the website aswell. Or kill the iis process in taskmanager (this is actually the fastest way to do it, and the way i do it myself)